# Can you measure the space-time interval using a meter?

Tags: special-relativity, units

The unit of the space-time interval is the meter:

$$
(\mathrm{d}s)^2 = (c \mathrm{d}t)^2-(\mathrm{d}x)^2-(\mathrm{d}y)^2-(\mathrm{d}z)^2.
$$

Can it be measured with a meter? How?

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that other users will know exactly what the issue here is.

Comment: Originally posted on SE [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/590377/name-of-instrument-that-measures-space-time-interval).

Comment: Are you using the word meter to mean two different things (the unit and the measurement device)?

Comment: Are you using the word "meter" in two different senses? Your first usage seems to be regarding a unit of length ("the meter"). Your second usage seems to be regarding a measurement device ("a meter"), e.g., a thermo**meter**.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Well the instrument that measures distance is a meter. The units of the space-time interval are also the meter. Either there exists a method to measure a space-time interval with a meter, or there exists two types of meters in nature.

Comment: But, anyways, yes, you can use a clock and a measuring stick to measure the space time interval.

Comment: OP, the "instrument that measures distance" is not "a meter." A meter is one unit of length. Do you mean a ruler? Or a meterstick? Or a measuring stick? Or a tape measure? Or what?

Comment: @hft So the answer is no; you need both a clock and a meter to measure the interval?

Comment: Again, "a meter" doesn't mean what you are using it to mean. This will clearly be incredibly confusing for everyone but you. But, anyways, yes, you use a clock (or any apparatus that measures time intervals) and a measuring stick (or any apparatus that measures length intervals).

Comment: @hft Well in French a meter is the name of both the SI unit and of a measuring stick of 1 meter. I assumed it was the same in English, sorry.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in relativity one can also measure distances with clocks.

Comment: No, in British English the length is *metre*, in French is *mètre*. In American English the length is *meter*.

Answer (score 1):

The spacetime interval between two events is the distance/time between them.

One simple case is when the two events are at the same point but different times in your frame of reference. Then you measure the interval with a clock.

Another simple case is when they are at two different points but the same time in your reference frame. Then you measure the interval with a ruler.

Other cases where both time and points are different are almost as straightforward.

Suppose the events are near each other but well separated in time. By this I mean it is possible to travel from one event to the other at a speed slower than light. The separation is timelike. If you travel between them at a uniform velocity, you have chosen a new frame where the points are the same, but times are still different. Because this frame moves with respect to your original frame, time dilations makes the clock run slower and you get a different time than you might have expected. This dilated time gives you the separation.

It is less intuitive, but the case where points are well separated and the times are near each other is just as straightforward. In this case, you would have to go faster than light to travel between the two. The separation is spacelike. You can travel from one event in the direction of the other. In this moving frame, the time between the two events is different from your original frame. By choosing your speed correctly, it is always possible to make the two event simultaneous in a moving frame. In that frame, you can use a ruler to measure the distance between them. That gives you the separation.

The last case is where the separation is light like. A beam of light can travel from one to the other. In that case, the separation is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The differential expression:

$$(ds)^2 = (cdt)^2 - (dx)^2 -(dy)^2-(dz)^2$$

is infinitesimal, so you can't really measure it with anything.

If you are asking about the interval between two events:

$$(\Delta s)^2 = (c\Delta t)^2 - (\Delta x)^2 -(\Delta y)^2-(\Delta z)^2$$

then you need a clock or stopwatch, and some kind of ruler, or some way to estimate the coordinate intervals via indirect measurements (say, for astrophysical events).

Regarding units, $c\Delta t$ has units of length, as do the spatial coordinate differences, so one would say the meter is the appropriate SI unit.

But: $(\Delta s)^2$ can be less than zero, so one needs to preserve the sign. You do that my leaving it squared, so now you have the SI unit "square meters", or maybe hectares in causal situations, both of which seem strange.